# The inclusion of $L^p(\mathbb R)$ and $L^q(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $p > q$, and I am looking for counter examples of continuous functions which is in $L^p(\mathbb R)$ but not in $L^q(\mathbb R)$ and continuous functions in $L^q(\mathbb R)$ but not $L^p(\mathbb R)$.

While restricting attention to $(0,\infty)$ it suffices to manipulate with functions like $x^{-\alpha} |logx|^b$ using indicator functions, but this method does not work if I want continuous functions and $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hint: look for functions that decay at different rates near infinity, e.g. Like x^-r for different r.

Comment: you may not find any continuous function for your purpose here, as if $f\in C(\mathbb R)\cap L^p(\mathbb R)$, then $f$ is bounded, so $f\in  L^q(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Arun, shouldn't an example such as this work, with suitably chosen rates of growth? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/continuous-unbounded-but-integrable-functions The boundedness should not be an issue.

Comment: Apparently it is not necessarily bounded

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to construct such continuous functions?@ZachBoyd

Comment: perhaps [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241488/the-exercise-regarding-l-p-and-l-p-spaces) may help

Comment: It looks like Eric's answer has most of the info you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $1 \leq q$.

Let $f_r(x) = \min\{1,|x^r|\}$.  Note $f_r(x)$ is continuous at $x \in \mathbb{R}$.  We see $f_r \in L^m$ for $m>1$ if $mr < -1$, which is to say, if $r < -1/m$.  Since $q < p$, $-1/q < -1/p$, and if we pick $r \in (-1/q, -1/p)$, $f_r$ is a continuous function in $L^p$ but not $L^q$.

The train of triangles function at [Continuous unbounded but integrable functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/482934/continuous-unbounded-but-integrable-functions) works for the opposite non-inclusion.

Comment: Shouldn't the max be a min?

Comment: @ZachBoyd : Oops.   Yes...

Comment: Is there such a function which is independent of $q$?

Comment: You could try the boundary case r=-1/p and see if the details work out.

Comment: I do not think this example works if I want it to be independent of $q$.

Comment: @zach : Do you have a condition on a function in $L^p$ of the form $r \leq [\text{something}]$?  If not, there is no way to put a function *in* $L^p$ and not in $L^q$ for $q \in (p-\delta, p)$ where $\delta > 0$ depends on the gap between $r$ and [something].