# $L_{\infty}(a,b) \subset L_q(a,b) \subset L_p(a,b)$

Tags: functional-analysis

If $- \infty < a < b < \infty$,   $0 < p < q < \infty$ how to prove that $L_{\infty}(a,b) \subset L_q(a,b) \subset L_p(a,b)$? Does anyone have any idea or some hints?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2241488/290189

Comment: Holder's inequality could be useful